# Parameterization of a curve equal to the intersection of a sphere with a plane

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

In the task it is necessary to calculate the curvilinear integral. But I was faced with the fact that I can not parameterize this curve in any way.
How can I parameterize a curve? $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2 , x+y+z=a$

Comment: Similar question and answer I found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114424/parametrization-for-intersection-of-sphere-and-plane-x2y2z2-81-xyz-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with spherical coordinates

$$x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$$

$$y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

$$z = r\cos\theta$$

Then apply $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2 \implies r = a$

$$x = a\sin\theta\cos\phi$$

$$y = a\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

$$z = a\cos\theta$$

Next use

$$x+y+z = a \implies \sin\theta(\cos\phi + \sin\phi)+\cos\theta = 1$$

$$ \cos\phi + \sin\phi = \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} = \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

which makes

$$\theta = 2\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}\right)$$

The reason we found $\theta$ as a function of $\phi$ instead of the other way around is because $\phi$ will wrap around the fourth and second quadrants and there is no inverse trig function that smoothly encompasses both. On the other hand, $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ which can be covered by one inverse trig.

Using the following facts

$$\begin{cases} \sin\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\cos\phi+\sin\phi\right)\right) = \frac{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}{\sqrt{2+\sin2\phi}} \\ \cos\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\cos\phi+\sin\phi\right)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+\sin2\phi}} \end{cases}$$

$$ \implies \begin{cases} \sin\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\cos\phi+\sin\phi\right)\right) = \frac{\cos\phi+\sin\phi}{1+\sin\phi\cos\phi} \\ \cos\left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\cos\phi+\sin\phi\right)\right) = -\frac{\sin 2\phi}{2+\sin2\phi} \end{cases}$$

we can have our final parametrization

$$x = \frac{a\cos\phi(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)}{1+\sin\phi\cos\phi}$$

$$y = \frac{a\sin\phi(\cos\phi+\sin\phi)}{1+\sin\phi\cos\phi}$$

$$z = -\frac{a\sin\phi\cos\phi}{1+\sin\phi\cos\phi}$$

where $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ (since the parametrization is $\pi$-periodic)

Comment: There is a much simpler parameterisation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114424/parametrization-for-intersection-of-sphere-and-plane-x2y2z2-81-xyz-1

Comment: @Aretino These parametrizations are equivalent by trig identities. Calling that one "simpler" is a mistake, since the hard work either has to be done earlier (by recognizing a general conic) or later (with pushing around trig functions). Personally, I've seen this approach (starting from a known coordinate system) to be more applicable to a wider range of applications.

Comment: @Aretino also the other post is still different enough to warrant keeping this question open. For one thing, constant of the plane is the same as the radius of the sphere, which is not true in the other case. I can see someone else being able to come up with a symmetry argument for another parametrization that would not be possible in the other post. Please reconsider.

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be reopened, anyway +1 for giving a third different approach.